# URL Rewrite no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-amigável, mod-rewrite

Veja se podem me ajudar.

Tenho uma URL assim:

```
http://www.site.com.br/portfolio-site/ilha-de-manhattan
```

Gostaria que ela ficasse assim:

```
http://www.site.com.br/ilha-de-manhattan
```

Sendo que ***ilha-de-manhattan*** é variável, de acordo com o item de portfolio.

Comment: esse é o seu unico post type? Ou seria o único sem o identificador na base?

Comment: não, tenho outros post-types. Mas seria o único sem o identificador sim.